# Username and Password fields automatically filled with phpMyAdmin credentials

Tags: html, phpmyadmin

I am facing something weird, the moment i hit my login page having a simple code in html with two input fields (username and password) shows automatically the credentials of phpMyAdmin. Here is my code..

```
<form action="check.php" method="post">
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" required/>
<input type="password" name="pass" autocomplete="off" required/>
<input class="input_line" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

i don't know why it is happening but figured out that removing the name attribute from the input field having type="password" solves the issue. please help me why this silly thing is happening. screenshot is added below.

[image]

Comment: Clear cached credintials in your browser.

Comment: It worked but only till i don't fill my phpMyAdmin credentials again. so i put "auto fill" settings of the browser off.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and this what I did. I filled the form with the username and password I wanted and clicked the submit button,when the browser prompted me with "save or not save", I clicked save, and the issue was solved. The browser I am using is Firefox.